# RoR YouTube Per User not per site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, youtube-api

I have a social application and I would appreciate being pointed into the right direction. I would like my users to link their YouTube account to their profile and be able to upload/view/delete movies from within my application.

I have another application (An estate agency) which I am using the gem youtube_it which works fine on a single user application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't done this myself it looks like you can do just that: you just need to use a different client for each user. From just looking at the youtube_it docs, it looks like you could have each user authorize your application via OAuth and store the access token responses on a per user basis. Then you could use the tokens returned to post videos. Check out the [Client with OAuth section under Establishing a Client in the youtube_it README](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it) for sample code.

See the [OAuth for Web Application documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks nbrew, I will take a look at the documents. When I have a working solution I will post a tutorial and link it here.